# QGIS Intersection tool not allowing Save file as Shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, intersection, dbf

In QGIS 2.16.2  I am trying to intersect two Shapefiles to create a third Shapefile, however the Intersection tool is only allowing Save file as DBR, CSV, XLSX or ODS - not SHP.  One of the Shapefiles was just made and saved using Intersection Run as Batch Process in this project.

If I start a new project and add the Shapefiles  I can intersect and create a third Shapefile.  I've intersected Shapefiles created from intersected Shapefiles  in the same project before and not had this problem.

*File1.shp*  intersect w/ *IntersectedFile2.shp* should make *IntersectedFile3.shp* 
   - Does not work in the same project where *IntersectedFile2.shp* was created.
Works in new project.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like there's no geometry in the result, and QGIS can only save it as a table. Do the two things you are intersecting actually overlap at all? Can you give us the data or examples that do the same?

Comment: I just tried intersecting two non-overlapping layers and could save a shapefile with 0 features, which seems to be the right thing. So that doesn't explain your problem, sorry. Think we need your data...

Comment: could be that you have a mixed geometry output which also can't be saved to a single shapefile

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.

I tried using the v.clean tool, then resaved and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  When answering here I would recommend thinking about a minimum length answer being "about a paragraph".